# Why workbox-webpack-plugin excludes files named manifest*.js(on) by default?

Tags: webpack, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

Is there a reason for having default value of `[/\.map$/, /^manifest.*\.js(?:on)?$/]` for the `exclude` option with both `GenerateSW` and `InjectManifest` plugins?

Answer (score 2):

The reasons are described here: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/1665.

Workbox 4 **does** include `manifest.json` by default.